# How to implement SCD type 3

Tags: data-warehouse, scd

A customer is changing the address let say 5 times.

How to implement CUSTOMER dimension using slowly changing dimension type 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! I don't like to paste links in answers, but I think, answer is lengthy one and SCD Type 3 already has number of implementation examples available. See the following links:

[Implementing SCD Type 3 with SSIS](http://chandunayakwadi.blogspot.com/2013/01/implimenting-scd-3-with-ssis.html)

and

[SCD Type 3 using SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2010/09/29/slowly-changing-dimension-using-ssis.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well the customer is changing the address at least 5 times. I don't think this is a good idea to track changes with `SCD Type-3`,(because it is not a slow changing dimension it comes under the category of rapidly changing dimensions well thats another topic but i must say you should look at it.) it means you are going to add at least 5 columns in your customer table, I am not good with Math. but i guess if you have 100 record in you db, you are adding 5 columns and each column length is `200 character`, you are going to grow your table `200*5*100 byte` considering a character is of 1 byte. And this is the rare case, other 99 customers have 5 columns added for free. The best way to keep track of it is via `SCD Type-2` change. I am sure you know how to do that with `SCD Type-2`

**Now how to do this with SCD Type-3**

`Step 1:
Add another column old_address
Step 2:
rename previous address column to address_n
Step 3:
update the affected customer data (old_address = address_n WHERE KEY = You_Customer_Key)
Step 4:
Update the address_n with new address`

For 5 time address changes keep iterating this 5 times. in `address_n` the `n` is your iteration.